# I can't get the country code in Flutter. Everything is either us or en

Tags: flutter, flutter-localizations

I can't get the country code in Flutter. Everything is either us or en.
It shows up as us or en even if I change the device's region or language. I want to show the language and region registered on the user's device.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Locale locale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
    String? localeCode = locale.countryCode;
    String? languageCode = locale.languageCode;

    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _currentIndex,
        children: [
          HomeScreen(localeCode, languageCode),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
class PomodoroPage extends StatefulWidget {
  PomodoroPage(this.localeCode, this.languageCode);
  final String? localeCode;
  final String? languageCode;
  @override
  _PomodoroPageState createState() => _PomodoroPageState();
}
```

Comment: Please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57977167/device-country-in-flutter

Comment: I can not success it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import 'dart:io';

String localeName = Platform.localeName;

Comment: Thanks , I want not en_US . i want en